# How to sort an object in a list on a non-unique value?

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting, icomparer

I'm trying to categorize articles by stored keywords. I have a list of keywords for a category, and I want an article to get assigned a category that has the most keyword count.

```
For Each keyword As String In category.Keywords
    category.tempCount += Regex.Matches(article.Item("title").InnerXml, Regex.Escape(keyword)).Count
    category.tempCount += Regex.Matches(article.Item("description").InnerXml, Regex.Escape(keyword)).Count
Next
```

And this is done for each category, ran for each article. I'm trying to sort the list in order to tell which category is the best one for this article. However it is possible more than one category is the best, and that none of the categories fit. So running this did not help me:

```
Categories.Sort(
Function(article1 As ArticleCategory, article2 As ArticleCategory)
    Return article1.tempCount.CompareTo(article2.tempCount)
End Function)
```

Maybe I'm doing this all wrong, but so far I think I'm on the right path. (I also have a default compare in the Category class, it just wasn't working either.)

I get an exception on the sorting most likely caused because they are not unique.

The exception I get is an InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. That's with using the comparer I built in the ArticleClass

```
Imports System.Xml

Class ArticleCategory
Implements IComparer(Of ArticleCategory)

Public ReadOnly key As Int32
Public ReadOnly Name As String
Public ReadOnly Keywords As List(Of String)
Public tempCount As Integer = 0

Public Sub New(ByVal category As XmlElement)
    key = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(category.Item("ckey").InnerXml)
    Name = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(category.Item("name").InnerXml)

    Dim tKeywords As Array = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(category.Item("keywords").InnerXml).Split(",")
    Dim nKeywords As New List(Of String)
    For Each keyword As String In tKeywords
        If Not keyword.Trim = "" Then
            nKeywords.Add(keyword.Trim)
        End If
    Next

    Keywords = nKeywords
End Sub

'This should be removed if your using my solution.
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As ArticleCategory, ByVal y As ArticleCategory) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of ArticleCategory).Compare
    Return String.Compare(x.tempCount, y.tempCount)
End Function


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) instead of [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx).

IComparer would be implemented by the class performing the sorting (such as a List class) while IComparable would be implemented by the class being sorted.

For example:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As ArticleCategory) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of ArticleCategory).CompareTo
    Return Me.tempCount.CompareTo(other.tempCount)
End Function
```

Comment: That might work... although I'm using LINQ to do my sorting now. Very easy to use no need to use the comparer thing.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found was using the Microsoft LINQ (a query language for objects) it works very well and quickly produces the right result.

```
Dim bestCat As ArticleCategory
bestCat = (From cat In Categories
           Order By cat.tempCount Descending, cat.Name
           Select cat).First
```

Completing my solution:

```
For Each category As ArticleCategory In Categories
    category.tempCount = 0

    For Each keyword As String In category.Keywords
        category.tempCount += Regex.Matches(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(article.Item("title").InnerXml), Regex.Escape(keyword)).Count
        category.tempCount += Regex.Matches(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(article.Item("description").InnerXml), Regex.Escape(keyword)).Count
    Next

Next

Dim bestCat As ArticleCategory

Try
    bestCat = (From cat In Categories
               Order By cat.tempCount Descending, cat.Name
               Select cat).First
Catch ex As Exception
    ReportStatus(ex.Message)
End Try
```

So this is my preferred method to do a sort or a query on a list object or an array. It produces the best result, in the fastest time without having to add the IComparer implementations to your class.

Check it out at [Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx)